# Azure Service Bus queues

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm new to azure cloud and my assignments requires me to implement service bus queues.

Question: Implement the Service Bus queues in your application. By using the queues and Service Bus, you will be able to manage the communication between the N-tier applications in Azure.

I have made a library management system using .net C# and not in MVC. and deployed it in the cloud. I don't know how to implement it.

Do i need to make new project for service bus or can i implement it on the existing system.
I have made a form page with Fullname, Email, Subject and Message Box. there is submit Button and onclick event can i implement service bus queue? help please. Thank you for time. Sorry for asking question in unclear manner. New to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have already create the service bus queue, still you may check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-portal for your reference.

Then, you need to leverage the nuget pacakges in your project so that you can send messages to and receive messages from a Service Bus queue :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues

For more related details : https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues.md

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-service-bus-queues/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-service-bus-and-queue-implementation-using-c-sharp-small-intro-and-sample-app/

https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/7.0.0-preview.1/api/index.html

Comment: Thank You very much. will look into these references. but i'm confused about one thing Do i need to make new project for service bus or can i implement it on the existing system i.e., Library management system asp.net c#?

Comment: I am not sure about the architecture you are following. I hope the links would help you. But if you just want to connect to service bus then you can do it in the same project. Again it might depend on your requirement and architecture.